# MacOS Faster Install of Homebrew and Package

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I have a bash script that makes use of a brew package. My problem is if I have a user run it on their own system, it takes 6 minutes to even start doing what they want. Needless to say, "The customer experience is lackluster..." Granted that is only the first time, after that it is quick.

Is there a way I can do a minimal install of Homebrew and a specific package quickly?

Comment: I don't think so. Some things just take a long time — longer, depending on what the user already has. For example, the user can install `brew` a lot faster if the Xcode command-line tools are already installed; but they probably aren't. And some packages take a long time to download and compile. When I use `rbenv` to install a new version of ruby, I can read several chapters of _War and Peace_ while waiting. Maybe you could supply some ambient music, or challenge the user to a game of Hangman...?

Comment: no minimal install that I'm aware of. what you could try is generating some debug output:
`set -x; /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"  2>&1 | tee /tmp/brew-install.out; set +x`

maybe somewhere towards the top of the output it will indicate what the installer is stumbling on?

Comment: There are two obvious options: A. include a copy of the package rather than installing and updating homebrew just for one package, B. If the package is not found, just complain that it's missing instead of trying to install it on the user's behalf (this is what most tools do, and it prevents the user from thinking it's your script that's slow)

Comment: This is too broad. Some Homebrew commands can be made faster but without your script we can’t know how to optimize it.

Comment: It would be better to point which brew package you referred to.

Comment: @bfontaine I don't *think* it's very broad… my understanding is the slow thing is the initial installation of homebrew.  Just following the standard install instruction quoted by @​todd_dsm above is very slow. 
 I have the same problem (in my case installing brew in a GitHub action as part of CI).  IIUC it used to be possible to shallow-clone the respository.  For my purposes, because the installation will never be updated, that would be enough.

Comment: Ah, in my case, homebrew is pre-installed for GH actions.  Doesn't help the original poster though.

Comment: Yeah I read that as "make Homebrew faster" but it’s only "install Homebrew then install a package". If the package has minimal dependencies and no significant compilation step, it might be worth installing it directly, without Homebrew. If that’s not possible, the shallow-clone installation method still works.